# How to display product category name on product.supplierinfo.tree.view on Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-view, odoo-11

I want to display related product category name in `product.supplierinfo.tree.view` on Odoo ?

Here is a *Vendor Price lists capture* :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a [**related field**](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#related-fields):

```py
product_category = fields.Many2one(
    string='Product Category',
    related='product_tmpl_id.category_id',
    comodel_name='product.category',
)
```

And add it to the tree view as usual:

```xml
<record id="product_supplierinfo_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.supplierinfo.tree.view</field>
    <field name="model">product.supplierinfo</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_supplierinfo_tree_view" />
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="name" position="after">
            <field name="product_category" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```